# Possible to use route helpers to redirect from a Rack app in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rack

I have a simple url shortener that base 62 encodes my Developer model's id number and returns something like this as a url:

```
http://example.com/d/dYbZ
```

I've mounted a rack app in my `routes.rb` file thusly:

```
  match '/d/:token' => DeveloperRedirectApp
```

... and my simple Rack app looks like this:

```
class DeveloperRedirectApp
  # no worky:
  #def initialize(app)
  #  @app = app
  #end

  def self.call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    token = request.path_info.sub("/d/", "")
    dev_id = token.b(62).to_s(10)
    if dev = Developer.find_by_id(dev_id)
      # developer_path also doesn't work since @app is not defined
      location = @app.developer_path(dev)
    else
      # same here
      location = @app.root_path
    end
    [301, {"Location" => location}, self]
  end  

  def self.each(&block)
  end
end
```

The problem is... apparently the initialize call is only sent a rails app instance if it's an actual middleware, not simply a rack app mounted in the routes file. A middleware doesn't make sense to me since this only needs to run if a url of the form `/d/:token` is requested, not on every request.

I'm just trying to do a simple base 62 decode, then redirect to the decoded developer id (if it exists, redirect to root_url otherwise). Is there a way to access the route helpers (ie, `developer_path`) or simply a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might simply be easier to do it with a rails controller that does the redirect. eg:

routes:

```
get "/d/:token" => "developers#redirect"
```

in the developers controller:

```
def redirect
  #magic goes here, use params[:token]
  redirect_to some_url
end
```

Comment: Yup, you're right. I was hoping to gain a little speed boost by doing it through a Rack app, but it's probably not worth the trouble. Thanks.